# Maximizing difference between three functions with 3 unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I am currently trying to calculate a way of separating the three following equations maximally, however I've had no luck. For those interested in electronics, it is from a custom voltage divider found [here](https://analog10.com/posts/rotary_encoder_analog_input.html).
The equations are as follows:

$x = \frac{3 * R_1 R_2}{R_0R_1+ R_0R_2 + R_1R_2}$

$y = \frac{3 * R_1}{R_0 + R_1}$

$z = \frac{3*R_2}{R_0 + R_2}$

The ideal case for me would be if we could set $R_0, R_1$ and $R_2$ in a way such that x,y,z has the greatest difference possible between 0 and 3, for example having x = 0.75, y = 1.5 and z = 2.25 would be a dream.

Does anyone know how I may choose my variables in a way that I can get close to the values I want?

All variables should be natural numbers below 100000.

Best Regards

Comment: What is your metric? That $|x|+|y|+|z|$ is maximal? $x^2+y^2+z^2$ is maximal? $xyz$ is maximal with $x$,$y$,$z > 0$?

Comment: $1/x=(1/3)((R_0/R_2)+(R_0/R_1)+1)$, $1/y=(1/3)((R_0/R_1)+1)$, $1/z=(1/3)((R_0/R_2)+1)$.

Comment: What I would like is for $|y-x| = |z-y| = |3-z|$ and for the absolutes to be maximal. Thanks

Comment: $z=2.25=9/4$, $1/z=4/9=(1/3)((R_0/R_2)+1)$, $4/3=(R_0/R_2)+1$, $R_0/R_2=1/3$.

Comment: Do you see what my calculations are driving at? If you want particular values of $x,y,z$, you can calculate the corresponding values of $R_0/R_2$ and $R_0/R_1$. Also, no matter what $x,y,z$ you want, you always get $(1/y)+(1/z)=(1/x)+(1/3)$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.

Comment: Thank you for your time, Gerry. Forgive my slow response.

Comment: I see what you are hinting at, however I fail to see how i can make z=2.25, while y = 1.5. Did I make it clear that $R_{0,1,2}$ is the same in all equations? If I do what you did to y, I get $R_0/R_1 = 1$ and if I do it to x, i get $R_0/R_2 + R_0/R_1 = 11$, now how do I choose $R_{0,1,2}$ to satisfy these three requirements? Best regards